# PhpStorm forcing file type

Tags: content-type, phpstorm

I have my script.php file in project. It contains javascript, but I wanted it to ne created dynamicly, based on server-side data.

I setted it's Content-type to text/javascript with php, but PhpStorm does not see it as javascript  file. So I loose javascript syntax hightlighting, error detection, live templates...

How can I force PhpStorm to see that .php file as javascript file?

Answer (score 4):

You could make a naming Convention for this type of file.

Something like

```
foo.js.php
bar.js.php
baz.js.php
```

And then go to Options `ALT + F7`, navigate to `File Types`, and register `*.js.php` to javascript

[image]

What you are trying to do sounds like bad practise.

You maybe want to have something like this:

A real JS File which is compileable by Closure Compiler or something like that, which provides "bootstrap" functions, which take your values as parameter.

And if you write this in your template.php, everything is fine for PHP Storm:

```
<script>
    doFoo(<?= $myFirstValue ?>, <?= $myFirstValue ?>);
</script>
```

Maybe you can work with data attributes in Your HTML which i think is cleaner then inline script tag.

Also take a look here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/126678/122683

Comment: When I do that, it recognises javascript, but now it doesnt't recognize php. When I try to add *.js.php wildcart to php alongside javascript, I must reasinge wildcard

Comment: Read the second part of my answer. You not realy want to do so. Take a look here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/126678/122683

Answer (score 2):

**`Settings | Template Data Languages`**

Find your file there and assign `JavaScript` in right column to it (or whole folder --then it will be applied to all files in that folder and subfolders).

This will tell IDE to use JavaScript instead of *default* HTML as outer language for that file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<<<JS` heredoc syntax to make PhpStorm highlight a specific part of your file as Javascript. For example:

```
<?php
echo 'This is using PHP syntax highlighting';
echo <<<JS
    <script>document.write('This is using JavaScript highlighting');</script>
JS;
```

You can also use file-specific language injection with ALT+ENTER, also see http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/06/language-injection-in-phpstorm/ for further details on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built-in Language Injection of IntelliJ (which is the platform on which phpStorm is built). For that, just mark the part of your file then press ALT + ENTER and use "Inject Language/Reference".